# Equation for RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential

I have the following circuit
[image]

I have solved the equation this far:
I have solved the equation this far $$ I_C + I_{R1}=I , U=I_{R1}R_1 \implies I_{R1}=\frac{U}{R_1}, Q=CV \implies I_C=C\frac{dU}{dt}, \frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{I_C}{C}=\frac{I-I_{R1}}{C}=\frac{I}{C}-\frac{U}{R_1C}$$
this can be solved as
$$ U_i=\Delta t(\frac{-U_{i-1}}{R_1C}+\frac{I}{C})+U_{i-1}$$
but for first order linear non homogenous we get:
$$ U=A \exp {\frac{-t}{R_1C}}+IR_1$$
I need the derivation to get this answer instead:
$$U_{i+1}=U_i\exp {\frac{-\Delta t}{R_1C}} +IR_1*(1-\exp{\frac{-\Delta t}{R_1C}})$$

I is not constant and can be a function of time

And R1 is R0 and R2 is R1 in diagram

Comment: I've moved the comments to chat as the tone all round did not add much to the site. In both cases @ChemEng responded to mild impoliteness with childish rudeness (without apparently noting that he was insulting some of the more capable members on the site). 
I'd suggest ALL try to be a bit more polite.
||
Comments [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113473/discussion-on-question-by-chemeng-equation-for-rc-circuit). fwiw.

Comment: Can you edit the circuit schematic so it's less ambiguous? @ChemEng

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, it is not completely clear what you're asking. But I will attempt to answer it as good as I can.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxpVol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{V}_2\$ (I assume that, that the voltage is you're looking for):

$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used Mathematica-code to solve for that:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I4 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, 
   I4, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R2 + R3) Vi)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> (R3 Vi)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I4 -> ((R2 + R3) Vi)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> ((R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/(
   R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> ((R2 + R3) R4 Vi)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))}}
```

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

$$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag5$$

- The input voltage, \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite equation \$(4)\$ as follows:

$$\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag7$$

Using Mathematica-code I found that:

$$\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)t}{\text{C}\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)}\right)\right)}{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag8$$

With the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=Vi = u/s;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[((R2 + R3) R4 Vi)/(
  R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), s, t]]

Out[2]=(R4 (R1 + E^(-(((R1 + R2 + R4) t)/(c R2 (R1 + R4)))) R2 + 
   R4) u)/((R1 + R4) (R1 + R2 + R4))
```

With your values, this gives:

$$\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\frac{9 \text{R}_4 \left(100\exp\left(-\frac{10000 (\text{R}_4+200) t}{\text{R}_4+100}\right)+\text{R}_4+100\right)}{(\text{R}_4+100) (\text{R}_4+200)}\tag9$$

With the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[3]:=u = 9;
R1 = 100;
R2 = 100;
c = 1*10^(-6);
FullSimplify[(
 R4 (R1 + E^(-(((R1 + R2 + R4) t)/(c R2 (R1 + R4)))) R2 + 
    R4) u)/((R1 + R4) (R1 + R2 + R4))]

Out[3]=(9 R4 (100 + 100 E^(-((10000 (200 + R4) t)/(100 + R4))) + R4))/((100 +
    R4) (200 + R4))
```

Comment: It’s ok if you don’t know how to solve it. Good try